# How Load a PHP script into div Same Window in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, refresh

I have error : data not define.
I'd like to refresh content into  from a php script who print html

My parent page :

```
<body>
variables ...
 <div id="comparateur2">
....
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").submit(function(e){
var format = $("#format").val();
var qtephotos = $("#qtephotos").val();
var option1 = $('input[name=option1]:checked', '#formulaire').val();
var offre = $('input[name=offre]:checked', '#formulaire').val();    
var val = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
        val[i] = $(this).val();
    });
var dataString =  'format='+ format + '&qtephotos=' + qtephotos + '&option1=' + option1 + '&valoption=' + val; 
$.ajax ({
type: "POST",
url: "scripts/ajax_comparateur.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(){
        $('#comparateur2').html(data);
    }
});     
 });
});
</script>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing your `dataType:` and data parameter in the `function()`

without dataType anything returned will be ignored, and without data in the function anything returned will be unusable.

```
$.ajax ({
type: "POST",
url: "scripts/ajax_comparateur.php",
data: dataString,
dataType: "html",
success: function(data){
        $('#comparateur2').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: That's wrong. If no datatype parameter is passed, "jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string)."

Comment: I'll give ya that, I fail to remember that more often than not as I tend to work with JSON or simple strings. Which leaves me with nothing to work with when I forget dataType, I tend to avoid XML which leads me to forget that jQuery will attempt to read it as XML.

Answer (score 2):

If your PHP script is actually working in returning data, then you should update your success call to:

```
success: function(data){
        $('#comparateur2').html(data);
}
```

The data parameter was missing from the function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't creating the anonymous function to accept the returned data as a parmeter. The data variable doesn't exist inside your function scope.

So instead of `function()` put `function(data)`.

Comment: This was already mentioned in another answer submitted before yours.

Comment: Sure, by a few seconds. I didn't see the other answer until I submitted mine.